# REST API, WebSocket and ZeroMQ in Scala. What to use?

Tags: scala, rest, websocket, zeromq

Let's say I have some service that talks over ZeroMQ sockets, and I want to provide access to that service to a single-page web application. I'd like the web app to talk to a service that provides a REST API (for control and queries) and WebSockets (for monitoring), and which does this by talking ZeroMQ to the first service. I'd like to write this in Scala.

What options are available to me for building that second service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very integrated solution would be to use Akka/Play2 for this.

Akka would be the core component talking to the ZeroMQ socktes via akkas [ZeroMQ Module](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/zeromq.html), which gives you a nice Scala-API and Akka/Actor integration. This Akka/Actor system can than be accessed via HTTP/WebSockets by using either [play-mini](https://github.com/typesafehub/play2-mini) or [play2](http://www.playframework.org/) which mainly differ in the style of defining HTTP endpoints.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, as I did decide to go with Akka's ZeroMQ module, but with Spray instead of Play.

Answer (score 2):

For REST API I would recommend [Spray](https://github.com/spray/spray) - a nice library with a very concise and flexible DSL for defining web services. We've integrated Spray into our current project and are pretty happy with it. As for play-mini, AFAIK, it depends on the entire play2 project, so you'll end up with a lot of stuff you don't need.

Comment: Spray doesn't do WebSockets yet, does it?

Comment: no it doesn't, take a look at this comment on the spray issue tracker on [github](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/134#issuecomment-20048958)